# Android opengl: Arbitrary axis rotation fails to apply rotation

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working in android with opengles 2.0 to render out an object and allow the user to manipulate the object. The user can rotate the object correctly around the fixed axis that the object begins at, but after an initial rotation has been applied, I'm unable to rotate the object around a new arbitrary axis.

As soon as there is a touch event, I reset the modelMatrix and apply the rotations that were already inputted by the user. The variable angle is a three element vector that contains the angle rotation for each axis.

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix,0);
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix,0,angle[0],1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix,0,angle[1],0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix,0,angle[2],0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
```

Then, I apply a new incremental rotation that was inputted during the touch event. This seems to work.

```
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix,0,newYAngle,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix,0,newXAngle,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
```

Afterwards, I try and calculate the arbitrary axis to add the incremental rotation into the angle variable. This seems to be where problems arise.

```
Matrix.multiplyMV(newAxisX,0,modelMatrix,0,new float[] {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f},0);
Matrix.multiplyMV(newAxisY,0,modelMatrix,0,new float[] {1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f},0);

float lengthX = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(newAxisX[0]/newAxisX[3],2)+Math.pow(newAxisX[1]/newAxisX[3],2)+Math.pow(newAxisX[2]/newAxisX[3],2));
float lengthY = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(newAxisY[0]/newAxisY[3],2)+Math.pow(newAxisY[1]/newAxisY[3],2)+Math.pow(newAxisY[2]/newAxisY[3],2));

angleChanges[0] = (newXAngle*((newAxisX[0]/newAxisX[3])/lengthX)) + (newYAngle*((newAxisY[0]/newAxisY[3])/lengthY));
angleChanges[1] = (newXAngle*((newAxisX[1]/newAxisX[3])/lengthX)) + (newYAngle*((newAxisY[1]/newAxisY[3])/lengthY));
angleChanges[2] = (newXAngle*((newAxisX[2]/newAxisX[3])/lengthX)) + (newYAngle*((newAxisY[2]/newAxisY[3])/lengthY));
```

After this code executes, the onDraw() method is called and the modelMatrix is multipled by the viewMatrix. That is then multiplied by the projection matrix and the result is fed into my shape class.

This causes a curving when rotating. For example, if I were to rotate the object 90° upwards with a y angle (on the 0.0,1.0,0.0 axis), then attempt to rotate the object 90° to the right (from the user perspective after the first rotation was applied), the object will curve downwards. I've logged the data from the axis vectors I'm using when applying the rotation, and what seems to happen (with the x axis vector) is that it starts out close to 0,0,1, which is correct, then slowly transforms to 1,0,0, which causes problems.

This is my current approach, but I've tried reversing the initial rotation and then applying the incremental rotation based on the vectors generated from that with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem in the short time since posting (even though it has stumped me for several days).

All I had to do was create a global rotation matrix that stored all the rotations performed on the object. I passed the changes in x and y in as a global variable from my touch event. These are then fed into a temporary rotation matrix, which is then multiplied by the global rotation matrix. The global rotation matrix is them multiplied by the model matrix.

```
    Matrix.setIdentityM(tempRotMatrix,0);
    Matrix.rotateM(tempRotMatrix,0,newX,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(tempRotMatrix,0,newY,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    newX = 0.0f;
    newY = 0.0f;
    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix,0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(rotationMatrix,0,tempRotMatrix,0,rotationMatrix,0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelMatrix,0,modelMatrix,0,rotationMatrix,0);
```